# Color ASCII drawing class

Tags: c++, console, linux, ascii-art

I am working on a pseudo graphical interface for a [Chess engine](https://gitlab.com/tsoj/Googleplex_Starthinker) I wrote. I want to draw a colored Chess board with [ASCII pieces](https://gitlab.com/tsoj/chessinterface/blob/f9361406014533fa167870943b34671ca5d96950/UI.txt). To abstract the pure `std::cout << std::endl;` I wrote this little class to organize an ASCII-character "framebuffer":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

struct Color
{
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;
};

class Framebuffer
{
  std::vector<char> charBuffer;
  std::vector<Color> textColorBuffer;
  std::vector<Color> backgroundColorBuffer;
  static const int frametime = 33;

public:

  const size_t width;
  const size_t height;

  Framebuffer() :
    width([](){
      winsize w;
      ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
      return w.ws_col;
    }()),
    height([](){
      winsize w;
      ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
      return w.ws_row;
    }())
  {
    charBuffer = std::vector<char>(height*width);
    textColorBuffer = std::vector<Color>(height*width);
    backgroundColorBuffer = std::vector<Color>(height*width);
    clear();
  }
  void clear()
  {
    for(auto& i : charBuffer)
    {
      i = ' ';
    }
    for(auto& i : textColorBuffer)
    {
      i = {255,255,255};
    }
    for(auto& i : backgroundColorBuffer)
    {
      i = {0,0,0};
    }
  }
  void setChar(size_t col,size_t row, char c)
  {
    assert(row < height && col < width && row >= 0 && col >= 0);
    charBuffer.at(row*width + col) = c;
  }
  void setChar(size_t col, size_t row, std::vector<std::string> box)
  {
    assert(row < height && col < width && row >= 0 && col >= 0);
    for(size_t rowOffset = 0; rowOffset<box.size(); rowOffset++)
    {
      for(size_t colOffset = 0; colOffset<box[rowOffset].size(); colOffset++)
      {
        setChar(col+colOffset, row+rowOffset, box[rowOffset][colOffset]);
      }
    }
  }
  void setTextColor(size_t col,size_t row, Color color)
  {
    assert(row < height && col < width && row >= 0 && col >= 0);
    textColorBuffer.at(row*width + col) = color;
  }
  void setTextColor(size_t col, size_t row, std::vector<std::vector<Color>> box)
  {
    assert(row < height && col < width && row >= 0 && col >= 0);
    for(size_t rowOffset = 0; rowOffset<box.size(); rowOffset++)
    {
      for(size_t colOffset = 0; colOffset<box[rowOffset].size(); colOffset++)
      {
        setTextColor(col+colOffset, row+rowOffset, box[rowOffset][colOffset]);
      }
    }
  }
  void setBackgroundColor(size_t col,size_t row, Color color)
  {
    assert(row < height && col < width && row >= 0 && col >= 0);
    backgroundColorBuffer.at(row*width + col) = color;
  }
  void setBackgroundColor(size_t col, size_t row, std::vector<std::vector<Color>> box)
  {
    assert(row < height && col < width && row >= 0 && col >= 0);
    for(size_t rowOffset = 0; rowOffset<box.size(); rowOffset++)
    {
      for(size_t colOffset = 0; colOffset<box[rowOffset].size(); colOffset++)
      {
        setBackgroundColor(col+colOffset, row+rowOffset, box[rowOffset][colOffset]);
      }
    }
  }
  char getChar(size_t col, size_t row)
  {
    assert(row < height && col < width && row >= 0 && col >= 0);
    return charBuffer.at(row*width + col);
  }
  Color getTextColor(size_t col, size_t row)
  {
    assert(row < height && col < width && row >= 0 && col >= 0);
    return textColorBuffer.at(row*width + col);
  }
  Color getBackgroundColor(size_t col, size_t row)
  {
    assert(row < height && col < width && row >= 0 && col >= 0);
    return backgroundColorBuffer.at(row*width + col);
  }
  void print()
  {
    static std::thread printerThread;
    if(printerThread.joinable())
    {
      printerThread.join();
    }
    auto printer = [this]()
    {
      std::string output = "";
      for(size_t row = 0; row<height; row++)
      {
        for(size_t col = 0; col<width; col++)
        {
          Color textColor = getTextColor(col, row);
          Color backgroundColor = getBackgroundColor(col, row);
          output += "\033[38;2;";
          output += std::to_string((int)textColor.r) + ";";
          output += std::to_string((int)textColor.g) + ";";
          output += std::to_string((int)textColor.b) + "m";
          output += "\033[48;2;";
          output += std::to_string((int)backgroundColor.r) + ";";
          output += std::to_string((int)backgroundColor.g) + ";";
          output += std::to_string((int)backgroundColor.b) + "m";
          output += getChar(col, row);
        }
        if(row != height - 1)
        {
          output += "\n";
        }
      }
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(frametime));
      std::system("clear");
      std::cout << output << std::flush;
    };
    printerThread = std::thread(printer);
  }
};
```

There is a bug: when destructing a `Framebuffer` it can happen that the `static std::thread printerThread` never gets joined or otherwise terminated.

Comment: ncurses. Perhaps you've heard of it?

Comment: In `setBackgroundColor`, take `std::vector<std::vector<Color>>` by const-ref instead since you don't modify the object. The copy is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

- Order your includes at least by portable / non-portable.
- Not a huge fan of omitting `private` and putting all the private members up top. IMO a class interface should go from `public` to `private` which makes for easier reading as a user.
- The whole thing is a bit hard to read. Some linebreaks and maybe even spaces would make this easier on the eyes.
- Is there a reason not to use `memset` in your clear function?
- Pedantic people might complain about the missing header for `size_t` and the missing `std::` qualifier.
- `std::string output = "";` initializing strings this way always looks weird to me. `std::string s;` should suffice but to declare intent more clearly you can do `std::string{""};`. Purely subjective though.
- Always a good idea to get into the habit of [using prefix operator over postfix](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59880/avoid-postfix-increment-operator) operator.
- I do like that you signal intent with `flush` as opposed to relying on `endl`
- Not sure if you use `Color` elsewhere but it could probably be an implementation detail instead of being free.
- You explicitly state this is for linux so you probably know that `system("clear")` is non-portable and are okay with it.

Comment: `#include <sys/ioctl.h>`
`#include <unistd.h>` are the non-portables, right?

Comment: @DariusDuesentrieb As far as I can tell, yes.

Comment: Interesting that you point out `std::system("clear")` as non-portable, when it's much *more* portable than `\033[m`...

Comment: @TobySpeight A fair point. Seems like my subconsciousness shielded me from even noticing those.

Answer (score 3):

## Framebuffer()

Could end with

```
    charBuffer = std::vector<char>(height * width, ' ');
    textColorBuffer = std::vector<Color>(height * width, {255u, 255u, 255u});
    backgroundColorBuffer = std::vector<Color>(height * width);
```

instead of calling clear.

## void clear()

Alternative implementation and let container implementation decide what is most effective.

```
    charBuffer.assign(charBuffer.size(), ' ');
    textColorBuffer.assign(textColorBuffer.size(), {255u, 255u, 255u});
    backgroundColorBuffer.assign(backgroundColorBuffer.size(), {});
```

## void setChar()

Don't copy the box in the interface, use a const reference. And don't call `size()` more than necessary.

```
void setChar(size_t col, size_t row, const std::vector<std::string>& box) {
    assert(row < height && col < width && row >= 0 && col >= 0);
    for (size_t rowOffset = 0u, boxSize = box.size(); rowOffset < boxSize; rowOffset++) {
        for (size_t colOffset = 0, rowSize = box[rowOffset].size(); colOffset < rowSize; colOffset++) {
            setChar(col + colOffset, row + rowOffset, box[rowOffset][colOffset]);
        }
    }
}
```

## void setTextColor()

Again, don't copy the box on each call. And another use of references inside the loops.

```
void setTextColor(size_t col, size_t row, const std::vector<std::vector<Color>>& box) {
    assert(row < height && col < width && row >= 0 && col >= 0);
    for (size_t rowOffset = 0, boxSize = box.size(); rowOffset < boxSize; rowOffset++) {
        auto & line = box[rowOffset];
        for (size_t colOffset = 0, line_sz = line.size(); colOffset < line_sz; colOffset++) {
            setTextColor(col + colOffset, row + rowOffset, line[colOffset]);
        }
    }
}
```

## void setBackgroundColor()

Similar comments regarding `setBackgroundColor`.

## void print()

Alternative lambda with `std::stringstream`.

```
    auto printer = [this]() {
        std::stringstream output;
        for (size_t row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            for (size_t col = 0; col < width; col++) {
                Color textColor = getTextColor(col, row);
                Color backgroundColor = getBackgroundColor(col, row);
                output << "\033[38;2;"
                       << static_cast<int>(textColor.r) << ';'
                       << static_cast<int>(textColor.g) << ';'
                       << static_cast<int>(textColor.b) << "m"
                          "\033[48;2;"
                       << static_cast<int>(backgroundColor.r) << ';'
                       << static_cast<int>(backgroundColor.g) << ';'
                       << static_cast<int>(backgroundColor.b) << 'm'
                       << getChar(col, row);
            }
            if (row != height - 1) {
                output << '\n';
            }
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(frametime));
        std::system("clear");
        std::cout << output.rdbuf() << std::flush;
    };
```